# After upgrading to El Capitan, directories on a SMB network volume are displayed unreliably

Tags: macos, folders, smb

After upgrading to El Capitan, directories on a SMB network volume are displayed unreliably. The volume has 567 "numbered" directories but when browsing the volume, some of the directories are suddenly gone (e.g. we need the folder named 328-60 and see folders from 316-00 to 377-20 are not "there"). Even if they reappear later, a double-click on the folder name kicks me back onto root level.

Any ideas on what is causing this or how we could analyze the issue would be highly appreciated.

PS: If it matters, volume is mounted via "Connect to server" and "smb://IP-address".

Comment: I've updated your question based on your feedback. Can you please have a look and (in case I missed/misunderstood something) edit it into shape directly (there is an 'edit' link below the question for this)?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @patrix. I really appreciate it!